# Google Charts - Multiple Category Filters - Restricting options?

Tags: google-visualization

I have 3 suppliers, 40 brands and 120 products, all displayed in three category filters. When a user selects one supplier from the Supplier filter, I want the Brand filter to hide all brands that are not provided by that supplier. Likewise, when a brand is selected, I want to hide the irrelevant products from the Products filter. I don't really care about what's being shown in the table at this point.

Is there any way to implement something like this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Charts: Creating summary charts after category filters have been applied (+ JSFiddle issue)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23525428/google-charts-creating-summary-charts-after-category-filters-have-been-applied)

Comment: Well, both questions are related to binding, but the other question is way more broad and it involves binding charts. I only cared about filters and so danabnormal's answer was short and to the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heres an example for you -

http://jsfiddle.net/danabnormal/cjn2tbbm

You can do this by creating a Dashboard. At around line 61 you can see that the selection made in the 'Sex' drop down is bound to the 'Name' dropdown, thus limiting what Names can be selected.

```
dashboard.bind(filterSex, filterName);
dashboard.bind(filterSex, pieChart);
```

Comment: .bind should be like
`dashboard.bind(filterSex, filterName);

dashboard.bind(filterName, pieChart);`, otherwise it won't update the chart correctly.