# Applying multiple filters to Google Charts Dashboards

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am facing problem exactly same as
[Google Charts - Multiple Category Filters - Restricting options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31246895/google-charts-multiple-category-filters-restricting-options)

My question is: if I have to apply three or more category filters with restricting options, how do I solve this problem?

My code looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <!--Load the AJAX API-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['controls']});

   function drawVisualization() {
    // Prepare the data
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Country', 'Region/State', 'Color', 'Population'],
        ['USA', 'California', 'Dark Green', 700000],
        ['USA', 'California', 'Light Green', 776733],
        ['USA', 'California', 'Dark Blue', 3000000],
        ['USA', 'California', 'Light Blue', 3694820],
        ['USA', 'New York', 'Dark Green', 2000000],
        ['USA', 'New York', 'Light Green', 657592],
        ['USA', 'New York', 'Dark Blue', 8000000],
        ['USA', 'New York', 'Light Blue', 3175173],
        ['France', 'Ile-de-France', 'Dark Green', 2000000],
        ['France', 'Ile-de-France', 'Light Green', 1093031],
        ['France', 'Ile-de-France', 'Dark Blue', 100000],
        ['France', 'Ile-de-France', 'Light Blue', 51372],
        ['France', 'Provence', 'Dark Green', 800000],
        ['France', 'Provence', 'Light Green', 252395],
        ['France', 'Provence', 'Dark Blue', 300000],
        ['France', 'Provence', 'Light Blue', 73556] 
    ]);
    
    // Define category pickers for 'Country', 'Region/State' and 'City'
    var countryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
        'containerId': 'control1',
        'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Country',
            'ui': {
                'labelStacking': 'vertical',
                'allowTyping': false,
                'allowMultiple': false,
                'allowNone': false
            }
        },
        'state': {
            selectedValues: ['USA']
        }
    });
    
    var regionPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
        'containerId': 'control2',
        'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Region/State',
            'ui': {
                'labelStacking': 'vertical',
                'allowTyping': false,
                'allowMultiple': false,
                'allowNone': false
            }
        },
        'state': {
            selectedValues: ['California']
        }
    });

    var colorPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
        'containerId': 'control3',
        'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Color',
            'ui': {
                'labelStacking': 'vertical',
                'allowTyping': false,
                'allowMultiple': false,
                'allowNone': false
            }
        },
    });
    
    // Define a bar chart to show 'Population' data
    var barChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'BarChart',
        'containerId': 'chart1',
        'options': {
            'width': 300,
            'height': 300
        },
        'view': {
            'columns': [2, 3]
        }
    });
    
    var pieChartA = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'PieChart',
        'containerId': 'chart2',
        'options': {
            'width': 300,
            'height': 300
        },
        'view': {
            'columns': [2, 3]
        }
    });
    
    var pieChartB = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'PieChart',
        'containerId': 'chart3',                
        'options': {
            'width': 300,
            'height': 300
        },
        'view': {
            'columns': [2, 3]
        }
    });
    
    // Create the dashboard.
    var dash = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));
    dash.bind(countryPicker, regionPicker,colorPicker);
    dash.bind([regionPicker,countryPicker], [barChart, pieChartA, pieChartB]);
    //dash.bind(regionPicker, [barChart, pieChartA, pieChartB]);//also tried this didnt work out.
    dash.draw(data);
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
</script>
<body>
<div id="dashboard">
    <div id="control1"></div>
    <div id="control2"></div>
    <div id="control3"></div>   
    <div id="chart1"></div>
    <div id="chart2"></div>
    <div id="chart3"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The third filter doesnt show up on the board. Not sure how can I handle this. Also what-if there is another category filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

each filter that should appear, should be included in the bind method with the charts.
add the color picker here...

```
dash.bind([regionPicker, countryPicker, colorPicker], [barChart, pieChartA, pieChartB]);
```

but you will need to allow none on the color picker, or only one row will ever be selected...

```
allowNone: true
```

if you have multiple pickers that depend on one another,
bind them in succession.
but there should only be two arguments passed to the bind method.

if the region picker is dependent on the country picker, bind as follows...

```
dash.bind(countryPicker, regionPicker);
```

if both the region picker and the color picker are dependent on the country picker, bind as follows...

```
dash.bind(regionPicker, [regionPicker, colorPicker]);
```

if the region picker is dependent on the country picker,
and the color picker is dependent on the region picker, use multiple binds as follows...

```
dash.bind(countryPicker, regionPicker);
dash.bind(regionPicker, colorPicker);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['controls', 'corechart', 'table']
}).then(function() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country', 'Region/State', 'Color', 'Population'],
    ['USA', 'California', 'Dark Green', 700000],
    ['USA', 'California', 'Light Green', 776733],
    ['USA', 'California', 'Dark Blue', 3000000],
    ['USA', 'California', 'Light Blue', 3694820],
    ['USA', 'New York', 'Dark Green', 2000000],
    ['USA', 'New York', 'Light Green', 657592],
    ['USA', 'New York', 'Dark Blue', 8000000],
    ['USA', 'New York', 'Light Blue', 3175173],
    ['France', 'Ile-de-France', 'Dark Green', 2000000],
    ['France', 'Ile-de-France', 'Light Green', 1093031],
    ['France', 'Ile-de-France', 'Dark Blue', 100000],
    ['France', 'Ile-de-France', 'Light Blue', 51372],
    ['France', 'Provence', 'Dark Green', 800000],
    ['France', 'Provence', 'Light Green', 252395],
    ['France', 'Provence', 'Dark Blue', 300000],
    ['France', 'Provence', 'Light Blue', 73556]
  ]);

  var countryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'control1',
    options: {
      filterColumnLabel: 'Country',
      ui: {
        labelStacking: 'vertical',
        allowTyping: false,
        allowMultiple: false,
        allowNone: false
      }
    },
    state: {
      selectedValues: ['USA']
    }
  });

  var regionPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'control2',
    options: {
      filterColumnLabel: 'Region/State',
      ui: {
        labelStacking: 'vertical',
        allowTyping: false,
        allowMultiple: false,
        allowNone: false
      }
    },
    state: {
      selectedValues: ['California']
    }
  });

  var colorPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'control3',
    options: {
      filterColumnLabel: 'Color',
      ui: {
        labelStacking: 'vertical',
        allowTyping: false,
        allowMultiple: false,
        allowNone: true
      }
    },
  });

  // Define a bar chart to show 'Population' data
  var barChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'BarChart',
    containerId: 'chart1',
    options: {
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
      hAxis: {
        viewWindow: {
          min: 0
        }
      }
    },
    view: {
      columns: [2, 3]
    }
  });

  var pieChartA = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'PieChart',
    containerId: 'chart2',
    options: {
      width: 300,
      height: 300
    },
    view: {
      columns: [2, 3]
    }
  });

  var pieChartB = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'PieChart',
    containerId: 'chart3',
    options: {
      width: 300,
      height: 300
    },
    view: {
      columns: [2, 3]
    }
  });

  // Create the dashboard.
  var dash = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));
  dash.bind(countryPicker, regionPicker);
  dash.bind([regionPicker, countryPicker, colorPicker], [barChart, pieChartA, pieChartB]);
  dash.draw(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard">
  <div id="control1"></div>
  <div id="control2"></div>
  <div id="control3"></div>
  <div id="chart1"></div>
  <div id="chart2"></div>
  <div id="chart3"></div>
</div>
```